# Load static data from project table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Currently using the JQuery UI autocomplete list function [JQuery UI - Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote). I have a project model that contains the list of projects. I want to get the list of all projects and display it through the JQuery UI autocomplete list function

This is what I currently have in my application.js file.

```
 $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );

        }
        var availableTags = [
            "0407 Dave",
            "0409 John" ,
            "0503 Michael",
            "0554 Jack",
            "0886 Daniel",
            "0969 Robert",
            "0971 Steve",
            "S006 Jack",
            "S006t Andy"    
        ];
        $( " #tags " ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
```

It can be seen that from the code above that it is displaying the list from the variable 'avaliableTags'. But I don't want this I want to be able to display projects from my project model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the data from the project model as JSON data. Create a page to access the data in the project model and return JSON data, then change the source to that page URL.

Comment: How do I go about doing it as I am still new to ruby on rails.

Comment: I'm not really an expert on ruby on rails as I regularly use PHP. It was just something written ont jQuery UI documentation about autocomplete. Maybe you can find somehting on [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/) or [here](http://pmwjournal.blogspot.com/2006/03/json-ajax-ruby-on-rails.html)